# Facebook Android SDK Login Dialog title bar issue

Tags: android, facebook

I've integrated the Facebook Android SDK with my application.

I want to remove the title bar from all screens in the app, including the screen in which the FB login dialog appears.

I've used the following code in the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".FacebookScreen" 
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
```

**FB Login code:**

```
      if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(FacebookScreen.this.getParent(),
                    new String[] { "publish_stream" },
                    Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                    new DialogListener() {

                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event

                            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error
                            Log.i("Login DialogError", error.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors
                            Log.i("Login Error", fberror.getMessage());
                        }     
                    });

        }
```

But still, I can see the default title bar appearing, when the FB Login dialog appears.

I tried to add the following line of code inside the onCreate method in **com.facebook.LoginActivity**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But that doesn't help either. How to remove that?